# Unable to import docx in python3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, python-docx

I have installed both python2 and python3 in my windows machine. I wanted to use the python-docx, so I installed it using pip install . But I am unable to use it in python3. I get these results when i try to import in Python2:

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny1bn.png)

In Python3 :

[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5ssT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Python packages are installed in a particular Python installation. You have two Python installations and it looks like python-docx is installed in only one of them. What you need to work out is how to target the Python 3 installation for the python-docx install.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions) seems to address how to manage that.